# How to use TeamCity REST API to get the builds which are in QUEUE

Tags: rest, queue, teamcity

Using "https://teamcity.com/app/rest/builds/{buildLocator}?locator=running:any" API can get all running and finished builds, but can't get the builds in queue.

How to get the builds in queue? Anybody know that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the TeamCity 8.x documentation available [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-QueuedBuilds) the GET call is:

```
http://<server>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue
```

You can also get the queue builds per project or per build configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is useful for me.